# В чём измеряется размер файла?

Tags: c++, файловая-система

В доках сказано, что [file_size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_size) возвращает результат в байтах. Имеются в виду октеты (8 бит) или количество `char`-ов?

Comment: Файловая система в принципе не знает про какие-то там char...

Comment: @Akina какой ответ это подразумевает?

Comment: Как полагаете, может ФС дать ответ в неизвестных ей попугаях?

Comment: @Akina это функция стандартной библиотеки языка, может выдавать что угодно. Из двух вариантов в вопросе выдаётся как раз количество `char`-ов, судя по ответам

Comment: По Вашим словам, если взять .TXT в UTF-8 и присвоить ему расширение .BIN, то он станет длиннее...

Comment: @Akina нет, не понимаю причём тут это. Я говорю, что стандартная функция языка программирования может возвращать что угодно, если это указано в документации. Это не зависит от того, что какая-то конкретная ОС может или не может выдавать. `char` определён в языке, хоть и не определён в какой-то ФС

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В той же [документации](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) написано:

> `sizeof(char)`, `sizeof(char8_t)`, `sizeof(signed char)`, `sizeof(unsigned char)`, and `sizeof(std::byte)` are always equal to 1

Известно, что `sizeof` возвращает размер обьекта/типа в байтах. Значит, `char` и есть один байт. Ну а сколько в байте битов зависит от архитектуры компьютера.

Comment: Можно ли тогда узнать результат именно в октетах? Проблема в том, что в коде используются точные типы (int8_t, например, должен быть ровно 8 бит, т.е. октет). Если запишу 2 таких в файл, то ожидаю получить результат 2 всегда, а не 1 на некоторых системах, где байтом считаются 16 бит.

Comment: @bob думаю, вы в своей жизни ни разу не встретите систему, в которой байт будет 16 бит

Comment: @bob Не уверен, что в системе, где байт != 8 бит вообще будут определены типы вроде `int8_t`.  Это ж просто псевдонимы для стандартных типов. Разработчики компилятора для такой системы вряд ли такое допустят.

Comment: @EOF согласен, в таком случае использую `int_least8_t`, которые будут по 16 бит на такой системе. Запишу их два и получу результат тоже 2. Вроде всё ок?

Answer (score 3):

Имеются ввиду именно байты. Поэтому, байты это `sizeof(char)`. А вот будет байт 8 бит или нет - это детали конкретного компилятора/операционной системы (да, на большинстве ОС, которые Вы встретите, байт будет 8 бит).

Если же хочется странного, то всегда можно почитать, что пишут здесь https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/intrinsic-types

И если после этого все ещё хочется, то делаем так. Подключаем нужные заголовки

```
#include <climits>
```

И потом появляется макрос `CHAR_BIT`, который содержит кол-во бит в байте на конкретной системе. Теперь дело за малым

```
your_size*CHAR_BIT/8
```

да, вдруг может оказаться, что там байт на 8 бит не делится (12 бит на байт), но тут уже самостоятельно решайте, то делать и как (вещественная арифметика в помощь). Но для 99% людей ответ 1.5 байта будет дивным

Comment: Можно ли тогда узнать результат именно в октетах? Проблема в том, что в коде используются точные типы (`int8_t`, например, должен быть ровно 8 бит, т.е. октет). Если запишу 2 таких в файл, то ожидаю получить результат 2 всегда, а не 1 на некоторых системах, где байтом считаются 16 бит.

Comment: Спасибо, забыл про `CHAR_BIT`